# Handle Done button ionic 5 capacitor appUrlOpen

Tags: ionic-framework, inappbrowser, capacitor, ionic5

I have an ionic app using authentication with openId using authorization code. When the token expires and the user needs to log-in the app calls into my identity server (Identity Server) by opening an inAppBrowser using the App plug-in from capacitor/core and performing the “appUrlOpen” `addListener` operation.

All works fine however I don’t really know how to handle the scenario where the user closes the browser within the app (pressing the X/Done option from the browser embedded.

I have read the docs https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app but I can’t find a way to add a listener or a handler for such event. **In my case I’d like to just close the app if the user does that action**. At the moment I’m not able to differentiate between that and for example, the callback of the authentication process.

Comment: I don't believe there is a handler for that done event. Maybe look for a fork of that plugin and see if anyone has implemented it.